# Sql - conditional subqueries

Tags: sql

Say I have a table with three columns,a b and c.
I want to query this table with three values, in such a way:

Select all rows where a = value 1

If there are less than 10 such rows, return those, otherwise select all rows within those where b = value 2

Repeat for c and value 3

Is it possible to do this within a single query?

Comment: This reeks of homework.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming SQL Server):

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM YourTable X
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN X.a = value1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),
        (CASE WHEN X.b = value2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),
        (CASE WHEN X.c = value3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
```

Comment: Thank you - yes, I would appreciate a comment for the downvote. I don't see anything wrong with this.

Comment: Almost what I'm looking for, except that if there are more than 10 results matching a and b, then all results matching a, b and c should be returned, even if more than 10. Sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: The above addresses your original question as it was written. I'm not sure what you mean by the comment, please explain in more detail if needed. You can remove the "top 10" if you want all results rather than only 10.

Comment: I'm sorry, let me try to express it more clearly: If there are 10 or entries where a = value1, then return those. If there are more than 10 entries where are a=value1, but 10 or less where a=value1 and b=value2, return those. Otherwise, return all entries where a=value1,b=value2 and c=value3, even if those are more than 10.